# Should this question be converted to Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

Should this question be converted to Community Wiki?

[Boss is sending me out of state for an 8-day class. Would it look bad if I asked for an extra day to do something fun?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/42943/437)

Many of the answers and comments are of the `This is what my company did...` variety.

Answer (score 3):

What would be the benefit of CWing this post?  CW is not meant to be a penalty but rather to give the community the ability to fix something broken, to make updates to something where the answers will frequently change, or where the comminity is needed to provide a complete answer.

I do not see this question as meeting those criteria.  This question is good just hard to answer well.  That is not the same as too hard for one person to answer.